# C# Write Csv file columns from string lines

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

so I am writing a csv file from a text file but there is many split formats that I am not sure how to figure it out

here is an example from the text file data

{Sll}  2022 Oct 04 14:55:06.838      [i] [Column 2][column 3] Loading text...

{Sll}  2022 Oct 04 14:55:06.838      [i] [Column 2][column 3 ] Loading text....

{Sll}  2022 Oct 04 14:55:06.839      [i] [Column 2][column 3 ] Loading text....

i need to select column 1 which is full datetime data (2022 Oct 04 14:55:06.838)

column 2 is the text Column 2,

column 3 is column 3

what i tried to select the date and time was and still not getting the correct data

any help please? i know i need to use lots of splitting and converting but not sure what is missed

```
 Match match = Regex.Match(TextContents.GetLineText(i), @"\d{4}\/\d{3}\/\d{2}");

 string date = match.Value;
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
    {
     var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy MMM d H:m:s.fff",  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
     Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString());
      }

     writer.WriteLine(date);
```

and

```
newfile.Select(line => DateTime.ParseExact(line.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2], "yyyy MMM d H:m:s.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal));
```

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(TextContents.GetLineText(i).Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2], "yyyy MMM d H:m:s.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Comment: Could you not just use WrieLine and specify the position you want the data? Such as `sw.WriteLine(String.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\"",\"{2}\", date, text, column 3));`

Comment: is it correct  "yyyy MMM d H:m:s.fff" ? I dont think.

Comment: And about regex I think it has problems also. Use this website to check your regex: https://regex101.com/

Comment: well guys, i know there is problems with my code, why do you think i was asking the question? lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved using the below code

```
 string delimiter = "  ";
                            int dateTimeLength = 24;
                            int dataTimeStart = TextContents.GetLineText(i).IndexOf(delimiter);
                            string dateTimeString = TextContents.GetLineText(i).Substring(dataTimeStart + delimiter.Length, dateTimeLength);

writer.Write(dateTimeString);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).